# Finding the centralizer of a given matrix without solving simultaneous equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is just something I've been wondering.

Given some fixed $A\in\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})$, I'm interested in finding:
$$C_{\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})}(A) = \{B\in\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})\mid AB=BA\}$$
For small $n$ (such as $2$ or $3$), you can just just write that $B = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$, and look at what must be true of $B$ for $AB = BA$ to hold.  This involves solving $n^2$ simultaneous equations, so quickly becomes infeasible.

What methods are there to find $C_{\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})}(A)$ (for generic $\mathbb{F}$ and $A$)? If we assume some "better" properties of $\mathbb{F}$ and $A$ (invertibility, $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{F}$ as something specific), does the situation get much better?

Comment: I think this is actually an open problem, except from some special cases as you can see here and in a lot of math papers.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105040/centralizer-of-a-matrix-over-a-finite-field